# Trying to use Search-Mailbox and Export-Message to save certain messages to eml format to network folder

Tags: exchange-server

Here is what I am trying to do:

I would like to search a mailbox for emails with certain criteria in the subject line and then save those email's to a folder on the network in .eml format.   My question is:

Is it possible to do that using: Search-Mailbox &  Export-Message together?

```
$strMsg = Search-Mailbox <Source Mailbox> -SearchQuery Subject:"<Text String>" -TargetMailbox <Destination mailbox> -TargetFolder <Folder> -LogLevel Full
Export-Message $strMsg AssembleMessage -Path "c:\temp\filename.eml"
```

How can I realize that?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use “;” to chain commands in PowerShell, for example:

```
$strMsg = Search-Mailbox <Source Mailbox> -SearchQuery Subject:"<Text String>" -TargetMailbox <Destination mailbox> -TargetFolder <Folder> -LogLevel Full; Export-Message $strMsg AssembleMessage -Path "c:\temp\filename.eml"
```

For more information, you could refer to this link:

[How do I run multiple commands on one line in PowerShell?](https://superuser.com/questions/612409/how-do-i-run-multiple-commands-on-one-line-in-powershell)

Comment: After more research, I am not sure its possible.    error message:   Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert the "Microsoft.Exchange.InfoWorker.Commo
n.Search.SearchMailboxResult" value of type "Deserialized.Microsoft.Exchange.InfoWorker.Common.Search.SearchMailboxResu
lt" to type "Microsoft.Exchange.Data.QueueViewer.MessageIdentity".
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Export-Message], ParameterBindin...mationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Export-Message

Comment: You could try " | " to chain commands in PowerShell. For example: Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited | Search-Mailbox -SearchQuery 'Subject:"Download this file"' -DeleteContent  For more information, You could refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/securitycompliance/search-for-and-delete-messagesadmin-help.